# QLineEdit Subclassing

Tags: c++, qt

I have Subclassed `QlineEdit`. Since I needed a specific operation on mousePress Event.
Now, as soon as I click the mouse on the subclassed QlineEdit (I call it CustomLineEdit).  I am trying to pop up a virtual keyboard. A new Window panel shows up, but the virtual keyboard is not showing up. I have checked for the correctness of the virtual keyboard by using it on other classes.

This is my code:

```
void CustomLineEdit::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *s)
{
    qDebug() << " Custom Line EDit is kicking";
    myKeyBoard->show(this); // once created keyboard object, use this method to switch between windows
    myKeyBoard->move(0, 0 + myKeyBoard->height() + 175); // to move keyboard
}
```

Btw, the virtual keyboard was downloaded from [this link](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/VirtualKeyboard?content=107388).

Any suggestions will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
myKeyBoard->show(this);
```

This `show` method needs a parent to drawing into this widget. If a widget is into another one, it cannot paint out of parent's work area. Maybe, if you change the line in this way, virtual keyboard will show:

```
myKeyBoard->show( parent( ) );
```

Comment: What do you mean? You can just show any widget in a main.cpp as well, without any parent.

Comment: You can show any widget in main.cpp without parent... if you force de painting... or you can set the parent to allow automatic painting

Comment: I do not force anything. `QLabel l; l.show();` will just work out of the box without what you are claiming.

Comment: If you execute that code, `l` will be shown in new window. Then, if you move main window, `l` doesn´t follow it. Otherwise, if you set a parent, you can show the widget in any place of parent work area. In other words: @Sheshadri sets `CustomLineEdit` as parent of virtual keyboard... because of this, the keyboard can only be painted in the work area of the lineedit... if @Sheshadri moves the keyboard widget out of this area the widget can't be painted.

Comment: OK, now I see what you meant to write.

Comment: @eferion you were almost correct, instead of "myKeyBoard->show( parent());" It is parentWidget(). I checked both and the parentWidget() worked.

Comment: Ok, then you can use `mapFrom` and `mapTo` methods from `QWidget` to place floating widget next to your `CustomLineEdit` widget.